# c# uwp : dispatch webview navigation and capture on each avaible logical cpu

Tags: c#, multithreading, webview, uwp

i'm learning code and doing an app that capture google streetview screenshost. Many screenshots. I want to find a way to parallel the queries.

Here the code for single query at time :

```
// prepare the html code  string in a dictionary (I use street view in a iframe)   
Dictionary<int, string> htmlCode= SetUpURLListHD();

// prepare the webview and display it on a grid
WebView saveWebView = new WebView();
saveWebView.Width = Width;
saveWebView.Height = Height;
TopGrid.Children.Add(saveWebView);

// navigate to string, wait a moment until street view completely loaded, do a capture, save it to file m.jpg with custom function
 for (var m = 0; m < htmlCode.Count; m++)
            {
                saveWebView.NavigateToString(htmlCode[m]);
                await Task.Delay(2000);
                await saveWebView.CapturePreviewToStreamAsync(stream);
                await SaveSSAsync(stream, m);
             }
```

I have 16 logical cpu, 64Go of ram, and a fiber connection. So, I want to do  until 16 queries at time.

For that, I think I need to write 16 functions to create 16 webviews :

```
async Task ProcessURLHD1Async(string url, int i, int width, int height, ulong firstFrameSize)
        {
            try
            {
                WebView saveWebView1 = new WebView();
                saveWebView1.Width = width;
                saveWebView1.Height = height;
                TopGrid.Children.Add(saveWebView1);
                ...
```

Second function :

```
async Task ProcessURLHD2Async(string url, int i, int width, int height, ulong firstFrameSize)
        {
            try
            {
                WebView saveWebView2 = new WebView();
                saveWebView2.Width = width;
                saveWebView2.Height = height;
                TopGrid.Children.Add(saveWebView2);
```

Etc...

I don't know if it's the right way to do that.
I'm now trying to execute the 16 functions at the same time, and when one ended, start again with next html code (next street view mage coded in the dictionary).
For now, no result. 
Any help is welcome.

Thank you !

ps : it's my first message after weeks of coding, thanks for all people who help on this site, very useful for me !

EDIT : Ok ! I found ! It's ugly, but it's fast ! :

```
// below namespace :

    public static class DispatcherTaskExtensions
    {
        public static async Task<T> RunTaskAsync<T>(this CoreDispatcher dispatcher,
            Func<Task<T>> func, CoreDispatcherPriority priority = CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal)
        {
            var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
            await dispatcher.RunAsync(priority, async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    taskCompletionSource.SetResult(await func());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    taskCompletionSource.SetException(ex);
                }
            });
            return await taskCompletionSource.Task;
        }

        // There is no TaskCompletionSource<void> so we use a bool that we throw away.
        public static async Task RunTaskAsync(this CoreDispatcher dispatcher,
            Func<Task> func, CoreDispatcherPriority priority = CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal) =>
            await RunTaskAsync(dispatcher, async () => { await func(); return false; }, priority);
    }

//Call function on click
private async void GetHDMT_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (outputFolder == null)
            {
                var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
                folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop;
                folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

                outputFolder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
                if (outputFolder != null)
                {
                    // Application now has read/write access to all contents in the picked folder
                    // (including other sub-folder contents)
                    Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.
                    FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", outputFolder);
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
            if (mylat.Count > 0)
            {

                await GetImagesAsyncHD();
            }
        }


 private async Task GetImagesAsyncHD()
        {
// Make a list of html code with street view iframe.
            var Width = 4000;
            var Height = 2000;
            var urls = SetUpURLListHD(Width, Height);


            WebView saveWebView0 = new WebView
            {
                Width = Width,
                Height = Height
            };
            TopGrid.Children.Add(saveWebView0);
            WebView saveWebView1 = new WebView
            {
                Width = Width,
                Height = Height
            };
            TopGrid.Children.Add(saveWebView1);
            WebView saveWebView2 = new WebView
            {
                Width = Width,
                Height = Height
            };
            TopGrid.Children.Add(saveWebView2);
            WebView saveWebView3 = new WebView
            {
                Width = Width,
                Height = Height
            };
            TopGrid.Children.Add(saveWebView3); WebView 
                saveWebView4 = new WebView
            {
                Width = Width,
                Height = Height
            };
            TopGrid.Children.Add(saveWebView4);
            WebView saveWebView5 = new WebView
            {
                Width = Width,
                Height = Height
            };
            TopGrid.Children.Add(saveWebView5);
            WebView saveWebView6 = new WebView
            {
                Width = Width,
                Height = Height
            };
            TopGrid.Children.Add(saveWebView6);
            WebView saveWebView7 = new WebView
            {
                Width = Width,
                Height = Height
            };
            TopGrid.Children.Add(saveWebView7); WebView
                saveWebView8 = new WebView
            {
                Width = Width,
                Height = Height
            };
            TopGrid.Children.Add(saveWebView8);
            WebView saveWebView9 = new WebView
            {
                Width = Width,
                Height = Height
            };
            TopGrid.Children.Add(saveWebView9);
            WebView saveWebView10 = new WebView
            {
                Width = Width,
                Height = Height
            };
            TopGrid.Children.Add(saveWebView10);
            WebView saveWebView11 = new WebView
            {
                Width = Width,
                Height = Height
            };
            TopGrid.Children.Add(saveWebView11);
            WebView saveWebView12 = new WebView
            {
                Width = Width,
                Height = Height
            };
            TopGrid.Children.Add(saveWebView12);
            WebView saveWebView13 = new WebView
            {
                Width = Width,
                Height = Height
            };
            TopGrid.Children.Add(saveWebView13);
            WebView saveWebView14 = new WebView
            {
                Width = Width,
                Height = Height
            };
            TopGrid.Children.Add(saveWebView14);
            WebView saveWebView15 = new WebView
            {
                Width = Width,
                Height = Height
            };
            TopGrid.Children.Add(saveWebView15);
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            Task t0 = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                for (var j=0; j<urls.Count; j=j+16)
                    await ProcessURLHD0Async(urls[j], j, Width, Height, firstFrameSize, saveWebView0, outputFolder);
            });
            tasks.Add(t0);
            Task t1 = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                for (var j = 1; j < urls.Count; j = j + 16)
                    await ProcessURLHD0Async(urls[j], j, Width, Height, firstFrameSize, saveWebView0, outputFolder);
            });
            tasks.Add(t1);
            Task t2 = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                for (var j = 2; j < urls.Count; j = j + 16)
                    await ProcessURLHD0Async(urls[j], j, Width, Height, firstFrameSize, saveWebView0, outputFolder);
            });
            tasks.Add(t2);
            Task t3 = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                for (var j = 3; j < urls.Count; j = j + 16)
                    await ProcessURLHD0Async(urls[j], j, Width, Height, firstFrameSize, saveWebView0, outputFolder);
            });
            tasks.Add(t3);
            Task t4 = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                for (var j = 4; j < urls.Count; j = j + 16)
                    await ProcessURLHD0Async(urls[j], j, Width, Height, firstFrameSize, saveWebView0, outputFolder);
            });
            tasks.Add(t4);
            Task t5 = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                for (var j = 5; j < urls.Count; j = j + 16)
                    await ProcessURLHD0Async(urls[j], j, Width, Height, firstFrameSize, saveWebView0, outputFolder);
            });
            tasks.Add(t5);
            Task t6 = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                for (var j = 6; j < urls.Count; j = j + 16)
                    await ProcessURLHD0Async(urls[j], j, Width, Height, firstFrameSize, saveWebView0, outputFolder);
            });
            tasks.Add(t6);
            Task t7 = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                for (var j = 7; j < urls.Count; j = j + 16)
                    await ProcessURLHD0Async(urls[j], j, Width, Height, firstFrameSize, saveWebView0, outputFolder);
            });
            tasks.Add(t7);
            Task t8 = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                for (var j = 8; j < urls.Count; j = j + 16)
                    await ProcessURLHD0Async(urls[j], j, Width, Height, firstFrameSize, saveWebView0, outputFolder);
            });
            tasks.Add(t8);
            Task t9 = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                for (var j = 9; j < urls.Count; j = j + 16)
                    await ProcessURLHD0Async(urls[j], j, Width, Height, firstFrameSize, saveWebView0, outputFolder);
            });
            tasks.Add(t9);
            Task t10 = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                for (var j = 10; j < urls.Count; j = j + 16)
                    await ProcessURLHD0Async(urls[j], j, Width, Height, firstFrameSize, saveWebView0, outputFolder);
            });
            tasks.Add(t10);
            Task t11 = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                for (var j = 11; j < urls.Count; j = j + 16)
                    await ProcessURLHD0Async(urls[j], j, Width, Height, firstFrameSize, saveWebView0, outputFolder);
            });
            tasks.Add(t11);
            Task t12 = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                for (var j = 12; j < urls.Count; j = j + 16)
                    await ProcessURLHD0Async(urls[j], j, Width, Height, firstFrameSize, saveWebView0, outputFolder);
            });
            tasks.Add(t12);
            Task t13 = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                for (var j = 13; j < urls.Count; j = j + 16)
                    await ProcessURLHD0Async(urls[j], j, Width, Height, firstFrameSize, saveWebView0, outputFolder);
            });
            tasks.Add(t13);
            Task t14 = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                for (var j = 14; j < urls.Count; j = j + 16)
                    await ProcessURLHD0Async(urls[j], j, Width, Height, firstFrameSize, saveWebView0, outputFolder);
            });
            tasks.Add(t14);
            Task t15 = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                for (var j = 15; j < urls.Count; j = j + 16)
                    await ProcessURLHD0Async(urls[j], j, Width, Height, firstFrameSize, saveWebView0, outputFolder);
            });
            tasks.Add(t15);

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }

public static async Task ProcessURLHD0Async(string url, int i, int width, int height, ulong firstFrameSize, WebView saveWeb, StorageFolder folder)
        {
            try
            {
                var dispatcher = CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher;
                await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                    saveWeb.NavigateToString(url);
                });


                await Task.Delay(3000);
                var kk = 0;
                var pixelised = true;

                while (pixelised == true)
                {
                    ulong thissize = await CaptureAndSave(saveWeb, i, folder);
                    if ((thissize > 0.7 * firstFrameSize) || kk > 5)
                    {
                        pixelised = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(1000);
                        kk = kk + 1;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

 public static async Task<ulong> CaptureAndSave(WebView webv, int i, StorageFolder folder)
        {
            ulong size = 0;
            SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap = null;
            InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            BitmapDecoder decoder = null;
            // Changes to imageElement must happen on the UI thread.
            await webv.Dispatcher.RunTaskAsync(async () =>
            {              
                await webv.CapturePreviewToStreamAsync(stream);
                decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
                softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
            });

                StorageFile file_Save = await folder.CreateFileAsync(i + ".jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                if (file_Save != null)
                {
                    using (var streamF = await file_Save.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        //StorageFile file_Save = await outputFolder.CreateFileAsync(i + "_" + equals + "_" + size + ".jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                        //< encoder to save > 
                        BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, streamF);
                        encoder.SetSoftwareBitmap(softwareBitmap);
                        await encoder.FlushAsync();
                        //</ encoder to save > 
                        //-</ Save Bitmap as File >-   
                    }
                }
                var basicProperties = await file_Save.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
                size = basicProperties.Size;
                while (size < 21)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(100);
                    basicProperties = await file_Save.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
                    size = basicProperties.Size;
                }
                stream.Dispose();
                softwareBitmap.Dispose();


            return size;
        }
```

Results : 118 capture (total = 139Mo) in 20 sec against 278 without paralleling !!! 5 GB of ram used at max.

Edit 2 :
To fast... there is an error in above code, I always use Savewebview0, when I correct (Savewebview1, Savewebview2....) the results is... 400 seconds...
All the work is do by the main thread I think, I need to create webviews in others threads, but I think it's not possible...
If anyone has a idea... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after many trials, I have good results.

The code is here for who want to use it :

```
public static class DispatcherTaskExtensions
    {
        public static async Task<T> RunTaskAsync<T>(this CoreDispatcher dispatcher,
            Func<Task<T>> func, CoreDispatcherPriority priority = CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal)
        {
            var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
            await dispatcher.RunAsync(priority, async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    taskCompletionSource.SetResult(await func());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    taskCompletionSource.SetException(ex);
                }
            });
            return await taskCompletionSource.Task;
        }

        // There is no TaskCompletionSource<void> so we use a bool that we throw away.
        public static async Task RunTaskAsync(this CoreDispatcher dispatcher,
            Func<Task> func, CoreDispatcherPriority priority = CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal) =>
            await RunTaskAsync(dispatcher, async () => { await func(); return false; }, priority);
    }
```

Above code below namespace delcaration.

```
    private async void GetHDMT2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (outputFolder == null)
        {
            var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
            folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop;
            folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

            outputFolder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
            if (outputFolder != null)
            {
                Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.
                FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", outputFolder);
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        if (mylat.Count > 0)
        {
            await GetImagesAsyncHD2();
        }
    }

    private async Task GetImagesAsyncHD2()
    {
        // Make a dictionary with html code string (with street view iframe inside .
        var Width = 4000;
        var Height = 2000;
        Dictionary<int,string> urls = SetUpURLListHD(Width, Height);

        //Code to estimate time for completely loading the first page (compute a time to use in await task.delay, and the size of first frame nextly used to know if image is pixelised or not (street view fisnish loading or not)
        SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap = null;
        InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        BitmapDecoder decoder = null;
        var k = 0;
        WebView saveWebView = new WebView();
        saveWebView.Width = Width;
        saveWebView.Height = Height;
        TopGrid.Children.Add(saveWebView);
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        long elapsed_time=0;
        saveWebView.NavigateToString(urls[0]);
        await Task.Delay(10);
        bool equals = false;
        bool findeq = false;
        int t = 0;
        int countTrue = 0;
        bool checka = false;
        List<byte[]> bytes400a = null;
        List<byte[]> bytes400b = null;
        await saveWebView.CapturePreviewToStreamAsync(stream);
        decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
        softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
        bytes400a = GetPixelsP(softwareBitmap);
        while (countTrue < 20)
        {
            await Task.Delay(50);
            if (checka)
            {
                await saveWebView.CapturePreviewToStreamAsync(stream);
                decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
                softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
                bytes400a = GetPixelsP(softwareBitmap);
                checka = false;
            }
            else
            {
                await saveWebView.CapturePreviewToStreamAsync(stream);
                decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
                softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
                bytes400b = GetPixelsP(softwareBitmap);
                checka = true;
            }
            t = t + 1;
            equals = EqualsByte(bytes400a, bytes400b);
            if (equals)
            {
                countTrue = countTrue + 1;
            }
            if ((equals) && (findeq == false))
            {
                k = t;
                elapsed_time = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                SlidetimeCompute.Value = elapsed_time;
                findeq = true;
            }
            if (equals == false) { findeq = false; }
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
        var elapsed_timeForTest = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        await SaveSSAsync(softwareBitmap, "0");
        ulong firstFrameSize = await GetSizePicAsync("0");
        TopGrid.Children.Remove(saveWebView);
        stream.Dispose();
        softwareBitmap.Dispose();

        double timeTowait = (double)elapsed_time;
        timeTowait = Math.Round(timeTowait / 4);

        // prepare somes grids
        var nj = 7;
        List<Grid> grids = new List<Grid>();
        Grid tmpgrid0 = new Grid();
        grids.Add(tmpgrid0);
        Grid tmpgrid1 = new Grid();
        grids.Add(tmpgrid1);
        Grid tmpgrid2 = new Grid();
        grids.Add(tmpgrid2);
        Grid tmpgrid3 = new Grid();
        grids.Add(tmpgrid3);
        Grid tmpgrid4 = new Grid();
        grids.Add(tmpgrid4);
        Grid tmpgrid5 = new Grid();
        grids.Add(tmpgrid5);
        Grid tmpgrid6 = new Grid();
        grids.Add(tmpgrid6);
        Grid tmpgrid7 = new Grid();
        grids.Add(tmpgrid7);
        Grid tmpgrid8 = new Grid();
        grids.Add(tmpgrid8);
        Grid tmpgrid9 = new Grid();
        grids.Add(tmpgrid9);
        Grid tmpgrid10 = new Grid();
        grids.Add(tmpgrid10);
        Grid tmpgrid11 = new Grid();
        grids.Add(tmpgrid11);
        Grid tmpgrid12 = new Grid();
        grids.Add(tmpgrid12);
        Grid tmpgrid13 = new Grid();
        grids.Add(tmpgrid13);
        Grid tmpgrid14 = new Grid();
        grids.Add(tmpgrid14);
        Grid tmpgrid15 = new Grid();
        grids.Add(tmpgrid15);
        Grid tmpgrid16 = new Grid();
        grids.Add(tmpgrid16);

        // add tasks
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (var i = 1; i < nj+1; i++)
        {
            TopGrid.Children.Add(grids[i]);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            tasks.Add(await AddTaskAsync(i, nj, Width, Height, firstFrameSize,outputFolder, grids[i], urls, timeTowait)
                );
        }
        // await all tasks
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    public static async Task<Task> AddTaskAsync(int i, int nj, int width, int height, ulong firstFrameSize, StorageFolder folder, Grid grid, Dictionary<int, string> urls, double timeTowait)
    {
        var t0 = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            for (var j = i; j < urls.Count; j = j + nj)
                await ProcessURLHD1Async(urls[j], j, width, height, firstFrameSize, folder, grid, timeTowait);
        });
        await Task.Delay(200);
        return t0;
    }

    public static async Task ProcessURLHD1Async(string url, int i, int width, int height, ulong firstFrameSize, StorageFolder folder, Grid grid, double timeTowait)
    {
        try
        {
            var Dispatcher = CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher;
            await grid.Dispatcher.RunTaskAsync(async () =>
            {
                var saveWeb1 = new WebView(WebViewExecutionMode.SeparateThread)
                {
                    Width = width,
                    Height = height
                };
                grid.Children.Add(saveWeb1);
                saveWeb1.NavigateToString(url);
                //give street view some delay to load
                await Task.Delay((int)timeTowait*5);
                var kk = 0;
                var pixelised = true;
                SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap = null;
                InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
                BitmapDecoder decoder = null;

                while (pixelised == true)
                {
                    await saveWeb1.CapturePreviewToStreamAsync(stream);
                    decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
                    softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();


                    StorageFile file_Save = await folder.CreateFileAsync(i + ".jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                    if (file_Save != null)
                    {
                        using (var streamF = await file_Save.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                        {
                            BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, streamF);
                            encoder.SetSoftwareBitmap(softwareBitmap);
                            await encoder.FlushAsync();
                        }
                    }
                    var basicProperties = await file_Save.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
                    ulong thissize = basicProperties.Size;
                    while (thissize < 21)
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(100);
                        basicProperties = await file_Save.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
                        thissize = basicProperties.Size;
                    }

                    if ((thissize > 0.7 * firstFrameSize) || kk > 10)
                    {
                        pixelised = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await Task.Delay((int)timeTowait*2);
                        kk = kk + 1;
                    }
                }
                stream.Dispose();
                softwareBitmap.Dispose();
                grid.Children.Clear();

            });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Best results is with 7 task in parallel. Why 7 ? Don't know. 
With single task, 118 captures (141 Mo) in 304 sec, with 7 tasks 58 secs !
Now, I need to find a way to adapt the code to different hardware and internet connection.